# SSL certification error with some Python libraries, but not others

Tags: python, docker, ssl, https, urllib3

I'm trying to make HTTP requests from a Python application but I'm encountering some odd responses surrounding SSL certification. I set up the following simple experiment:

Test scenario: Send `GET` request to `https://example.com`

|  | Within Docker container | Outside Docker container |
| --- | --- | --- |
| requests | SSL cert error | SSL cert error |
| httpx | SSL cert error | SSL cert error |
| urllib3 | SSL cert error | No error |
| Postman | N/A | No error |
| cURL | N/A | No error |

The `SSL cert error` is always a variation of this:

```py
httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)
```

I sent all these requests while on my company's VPN. If I disable the VPN I get an error relating to a proxy:

```py
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x105bb03a0>: Failed to resolve <company_proxy_url_here> ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)")))
```

Is anyone able see if the issue is VPN related, library related, or Docker related? Or some combination of them all?

Comment: I would guess your company has added a CA certificate to your system so that you will accept certificates signed by their web proxy, allowing them to inspect the web traffic.  It's never exposed within docker, and for whatever reason https and requests aren't picking it up, but urllib3, postman, and curl is.  When you're not on the VPN your proxy settings don't work so that stops you from making the connection in the first place.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable explanation. Seems like I need to find out how to expose the certificate within the container.